# Accessing rake task variables in controller and Scheduling rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, scheduling

1. I have a rake task `send_emails` which send e-mails to lot of people. I call this rake task from controller as mentioned in [Rake in Background](http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background) railscast. But I want to schedule this   rake task to run at a particular date and time, which is not same for everyday (it's not a  cron job). **The date and time are set dynamically from a form.**
2. For the above implemented rake task for sending emails, I want to show the status of the mailing process to the end-user. For instance, say there is a `response` object in the rake task which I can use as `response.status`,`response.delivered?`,`response.address`, etc. How can I access this object ( or any variable) in the rake file in my controller?

I don't want to use `delayed_job` but want to implement it's functionality of **`run_at` and `in_the_future`.** Also the `whenever` gem won't be able to solve my first problem coz I won't be able to pass date and time to it's scheduler.

Comment: Well you can't access the rake tasks variable in controller. What I would like to suggest is add table in DB & add the status of each email delivery into that table. Use that table data to show the status of rake task to user.

Comment: @madyrockss What about scheduling?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the rails mailers to take care of mailing?

Comment: I think maybe you should reconsider delayed_job, as you need a "cronic" thing to continually check for jobs and run them. You can se the job date and time to the one set in the form.

Comment: @NoahDavis beacause I'm sending a lot of emails. so that will hung up my rails app. It will wait for all the mails to deliver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, calling rake task from controller is a bad practice. Ryan published that video at 2008 since that many better solution have came up. You shouldn't ignore it.

I suggest you to use `delayed_job`, it serves your needs in a great way. Since, if you want to  invoke task dynamically, there should be some checker which will continuously check the desire field every second. Delayed job keep checking its database every time, you can use that.

Anyway,You can use something like this

```
def self.run_when
  Scheduler.all.each do |s|
    if d.dynamically_assigned_field < 1.second.ago
       d.run_my_job!
       d.status = "finished"
       d.save
    end
  end
end
```

And, in model you can do something like this

```
 def run_my_job!
   self.status = "processing"
   self.save
   long_running_task
 end
```

One thing also you should keep in mind that if too many workers/batch/cron job starts at run at same it will fight for resources and may enter into deadlock state. As per your server capacity, you should limit the running jobs.

Sidekiq is also a good option you can consider. Personally, i like sidekiq because it doesn't hit my database everytime , scales very effectively. It uses redis  but it is expensive.

Comment: What about scheduling tasks? I know there are plenty of gems available for scheduled jobs.But I want to implement this myself. For scheduling should I do something like. `time_remaining = scheduled_time - Time.now` and then using it as `time_remaining_in_minutes.minutes.from_now call_rake_task` or something like that?

Comment: yes, your approach is correct. And, i am not forcing you to use any gem, just suggestion. In above example, `Scheduler` was just an model name which is manually implemented to deal scheduling tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I would create new model for mail job, like this:

**app/models/mail_job.rb**

```
class MailJob

    attr_accessible :email, :send_at, :delivered

    scope :should_deliver, -> { where(delivered: false).where('send_at <= ?', Time.now) }

    def should_deliver?
        !delivered? && send_at <= Time.now 
    end        

    ...   

end
```

And use [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) + [Sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq), running every minute (or any other interval) and checking for mail jobs that should be delivered.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry but I Didn't understood what you did.

Comment: I have suggested to create a model with table in DB, that you can use afterwards like this: `MailJob.should_deliver.each(&:deliver!)`. But, of course, you should implement your own `deliver!` method in this class.

Comment: @whoIsCraig Was my answer helpful for you?